# Halo 4 Campaign Multiplayer

Tags: xbox-360, halo-4

Before I start I don't have a lot of friends who play halo 4 on Xbox.

So my question is it possible to play the campaign with other players/strangers. I want to know about this so I can buy a gold membership.
P.S : I use Xbox 360

Answer (score 1):

You can play an online co-op campaign, but *only* through using invites, *and* before starting a game. Players cannot join a session-in-progress during campaign. This is due to certain aspects of levels needing to be re-loaded when more than one player is present. The co-op partner does not have to be on your friends list to be able to play in campaign (or matchmaking) with the host.